# How to keep a higher-up focused on the main subject of the meeting?

Tags: internship

I am in an internship and new to the workspace world. I don't really know how to deal with this.

For my project I need to ask questions to a higher-up that is not on my team. He is based in another city and the meeting are done through Teams. I already met him physically and it was a bit better but not by a lot.

Before the meeting, I prepare every questions I have at the time and the context of my project.
When we are talking, he focus on details wich either feel less important or will come in the future but still dont impact me, but I may be wrong.
He also like to talk a lot and I have difficulties to just ask my questions as he keep giving exemples and explainations for the last one. I think he fear that I didn't understand what he said.

At the end, I have very few questions answered and a lot of new entries for futures things to do, or think of. I am still stuck on most of the project and need to reschedule another meeting.

Do you have any advice on how to exit the meeting with more question answered ?

Comment: Try asking the questions in E-mail, so he has a checklist of what he has and hasn't answered?

Comment: _“I think he fear that I didn't understand what he said.”_ — a general approach for this is to demonstrate your understanding by reflecting back to them, using different words and/or summarising. E.g. “Ah, so you're saying I need to frob the foo? Yes, that makes sense.” That should set any fears at rest. (Of course, that can help identify anything you _don't_ fully understand, too.)

Comment: You need to take charge of the meeting. In other words, you need to cut him and off and get him to move to the next item on the agenda. As an intern, I know this is an extremely difficult thing to do and this feels wrong, but sometimes, that can be the only viable option.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they are very helpful and I will try these ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a clear meeting agenda. Share the agenda at least several hours before the meeting. It should be detailed enough that it's clear what information you are seeking, and maybe what documents your colleague needs to bring, but no huge wall of text which doesn't get read. In all meetings in the workplace its very important that every participant knows exactly what's the scope and what is needed by them.

If your colleague goes off on a tangent, don't be shy to interrupt and ask if this is important for your next steps, and if we may return to the agenda.

After your meeting time is over, thank him for his time. If some agenda bullet points didn't get covered, it's now obvious to him that he talked too much, or the meeting time was not enough. Don't feel bad to ask for a followup, and schedule that immediately.

Comment: That make sense. I realise he simply don't see all the questions I want to ask him, so he share as much knowledge as he can on each one.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things at play that I see. The first is that you don't (and can't) have the information and experience to see and understand this person's goals for the meeting. That doesn't mean you shouldn't understand the purpose of the meeting. It means that you can't know what other intangible objectives this person has for the meeting. So in that vein, keep in mind and have some patience knowing that there may be a purpose being served to which you're not informed.

The second thing is the core of what you need action on. You are exiting the meeting without clear goals and guidance. I'm going to assume inattention on the part of your leader in that they probably are not aware of that. Given the manner in which this question was asked, I would suspect that you regularly end the meetings with pleasantries and acceptance language that leads them to believe you DO have the information you need to continue.

You need to have a meeting with this person to set communication expectations as well as to inform them that the style of the meeting is leaving you unprepared and ill-informed. You should set a specific purpose for this meeting, and it should be stated clearly. I would suggest something like "Establishing communication expectations such that each [meeting type] results in both of us having clear goals and expectations." It would be good to set an agenda that itemizes each of the behaviors that leave you with more questions.

Try to state the request in a manner that suggests you're looking to be more effective to their purposes rather than just wanting to complain about the way they conduct a meeting. Using language such as "I feel unprepared in helping you achieve the team's goals" or "Some of these discussions are leaving me unable to help the team".

You're not going to get any action or resolution unless you bring it up directly with them and address it specifically with the purpose of making you more effective in achieving the team's goals as well as their goals for the team.

Comment: I would tread carefully.  IMHO, instead of an "I feel unprepared" statement, a more positive statement such as "I could help more if ...." would work better.

Comment: @JosephDoggie - I can get next to that change in language. I would say it depends on the individual. Your version would very likely be more in line with OP's manner of delivery. I'm also not one to tread carefully XD.

Comment: Is it a common meeting to set with someone ? He is not directly my leader and even if he is open, I don't think it's the kind of things he is used to or have time for.

Comment: If you have direct interaction with this person of any kind, then it's completely appropriate to have a meeting on this topic.